# Does "have you not scolded by any" make any sense?

Tags: american-english

While chatting with a friend I used the phrase "have you not scolded by any". But it doesn't sound correct. Does it make any sense?

Comment: That phrase does not make any sense.  Can you provide more of the context in which you said it?  Maybe one of us can help you to correct it, but we need more information to be able to do so.  Also, _veracity_ is not the correct word; _correctness_ is.

Comment: It should probably be _"Haven't you been scolded by any...?_"

Comment: @BillFranke, yeah I was thinking along the same lines, more grammatical as _Haven't you been scolded by anyone?_ or _Hasn't anyone scolded you?_ But until OP clarifies, it is impossibly unclear, methinks...

Comment: I think as it stands this question is Too Localised. The string of words you've given makes no sense. Unless you at least tell us what you *wanted* to express, how can we guess what you should have said?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is "have you scolded any" if you are asking your friend if s/he scolded somebody, or "have you been scolded by any[body]" if you are asking your friend if somebody scolded her/him.
In the latter case, *by any* is probably not necessary, except when you are saying, for example, "by any of your relatives."

Comment: *by any* is not so much unnecessary as incomprehensible: by any *what*?

Comment: Isn't _any_ used to refer to people too? "They are unlikely to be known by name to any but specialists."